# Is there a Python idiom for the last n elements of a sequence?

Tags: python

e.g., for a sequence of unknown length, what is the most "Pythonic" way of getting the last n elements?

Obviously I could calculate the starting and ending indices. Is there anything slicker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by using negative indices:

```
last_five = somesequence[-5:]
```

Negative indices in a slice are relative to the sequence length.

Answer (score 1):

Use negative indexing.

`seq[-1]` is the last element of a sequence. `seq[-3:]` gives you the last three.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sequence[-n:]
```

(text to make Stack Overflow happy)